# Every so often ESP8266 hangs... WifiClient seems to be at fault

Tags: esp8266, networking

This code works fine without any freezes:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

Servo turn;

ESP8266WiFiMulti wifiMulti;

const char* host = "192.168.1.148";
WiFiClient client;

int turnPos = 90;
unsigned long ts = 0;

void setup() {
  startWiFi();
  turn.attach(14);
  turn.write(90);
}

void loop() {

  if (millis() - ts > 500 && millis() - ts < 1000) {
    turnPos = 160;
  }
  else if (millis() - ts >= 1000) {
    ts = millis();
  }
  else {
    turnPos = 20;
  }


  /*if (client.connected()) {
    }
    else {
    if (!client.connect(host, 3000)) {
    }
    }*/


  turn.write(turnPos);
  yield();
}

void startWiFi() {
  wifiMulti.addAP("DVW3201BE8", "###");   // password is filled in on mny version
  while (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect: scan for Wi-Fi networks, and connect to the strongest of the networks above
    delay(250);
    Serial.print('.');
  }
}
```

While this code (with the wificlient bit commented out) freezes every so often:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

Servo turn;

ESP8266WiFiMulti wifiMulti;

const char* host = "192.168.1.148";
WiFiClient client;

int turnPos = 90;
unsigned long ts = 0;

void setup() {
  startWiFi();
  turn.attach(14);
  turn.write(90);
}

void loop() {

  if (millis() - ts > 500 && millis() - ts < 1000) {
    turnPos = 160;
  }
  else if (millis() - ts >= 1000) {
    ts = millis();
  }
  else {
    turnPos = 20;
  }


  if (client.connected()) {
    }
    else {
    if (!client.connect(host, 3000)) {
    }
    }


  turn.write(turnPos);
  yield();
}

void startWiFi() {
  wifiMulti.addAP("DVW3201BE8", "###");   // password is filled in on mny version
  while (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) { // Wait for the Wi-Fi to connect: scan for Wi-Fi networks, and connect to the strongest of the networks above
    delay(250);
    Serial.print('.');
  }
}
```

Only difference is in the working one the WifiClient bit of code is commented out.   How would WifiClient cause this problem?

Comment: fun with esp8266. try new core package 2.4.2

Comment: I see you're using `String` in a terrible way. If this snippet is anything to go by you're probably doing the same thing elsewhere, and making swiss cheese of your heap.

Comment: The problem still occurs without the String bit -- I have edited my question to include all of my code.

Comment: yes and this is fixed in latest version of arduino esp8266 core

Comment: Are you sure?   How can I check the version?   Because I think I have the most updated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug and it was fixed in Arduino esp8266 core package 2.4.2 published 2 days ago.

see first line in ESP8266WiFi section of the [changes list](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/releases)

> 2.4.2 ESP8266WiFi:
>   Fix memory leak when reusing WiFiClient object (#4497, #4516, #4549)